# Pandas: How to efficiently select rows based on string subsets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, let's say

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[8,6,7,5],"B":["cat", "hat","","d"],"C":[3,5,4,0]})
```

I want to select all rows in which column B ends in 'at'.  I have no guarantee on the existence of an entry in column B, and I have no guarantee about how long the string is if it's there.  I know I could basically write a for-loop for that, but I'm wondering if that's the best solution, elegance- and performance-wise.

Comment: `df.B.str.endswith('at')`.  If you care about performance, use a list comprehension with the python method, instead of the string accessor

Comment: Replace `contains` with `endswith` in the linked duplicate above.